# SSJS Update and Perform Query Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

I am attempting to loop through data extension content to dynamically update and perform a query definition. Essentially, I'd like to update and run the same Query Definition synchronously using SSJS but the following code is not working. Is this even possible using the [QD functions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/query_definition_server_side_javascript_functions/)?

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">

    function queryUpdatePerform(qd, Query, UpdateType) {
        qd = QueryDefinition.Init(qd);
        var update_status = qd.Update({
        QueryText: Query, TargetUpdateType: UpdateType
        });
        var perform_status = qd.Perform();
        var status = "{Update:".concat(update_status).concat(", ").concat("Perform:").concat(perform_status).concat("}"); 
        return status;
    }

    var QD_ExternalKey = "qd-externalkey";
    var DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey = "de-externalkey";
    var contentDetailsDE = DataExtension.Init(DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey);
    var contentDetails = contentDetailsDE.Rows.Retrieve();

    for (var i = 0; i < contentDetails.length; i++ ) {
        var QueryLogic = contentDetails[i].QueryLogic;
        var Query = "SELECT * FROM [SourceDE] WHERE EmailAddress IS NOT NULL AND ".concat(QueryLogic);

        var status = "";
        var ut = "";
        if (i === 0) {
            ut = "Overwrite";
            status = queryUpdatePerform(QD_ExternalKey, Query, ut); 
        } else {
            ut = "Update";
            status = queryUpdatePerform(QD_ExternalKey, Query, ut);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where you have declared l variable in your code?

Comment: Hi @PalashRai - this is a copy/paste error. The variable that was "l" should have been "i".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly and only have to added `SSJS library` in top of the code and need to change 'l' variable to 'i'.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    function queryUpdatePerform(qd, Query, UpdateType) {
        qd = QueryDefinition.Init(qd);
        var update_status = qd.Update({
        QueryText: Query, TargetUpdateType: UpdateType
        });
        var perform_status = qd.Perform();
        var status = "{Update:".concat(update_status).concat(", ").concat("Perform:").concat(perform_status).concat("}"); 
        return status;
    }

    var QD_ExternalKey = "qd-externalkey";
    var DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey = "de-externalkey";
    var contentDetailsDE = DataExtension.Init(DE_ContentDetails_ExternalKey);
    var contentDetails = contentDetailsDE.Rows.Retrieve();

    for (var i = 0; i < contentDetails.length; i++ ) {
        var QueryLogic = contentDetails[i].QueryLogic;
        var Query = "SELECT * FROM [SourceDE] WHERE EmailAddress IS NOT NULL AND ".concat(QueryLogic);

        var status = "";
        var ut = "";
        if (i === 0) {
            ut = "Overwrite";
            status = queryUpdatePerform(QD_ExternalKey, Query, ut); 
        } else {
            ut = "Update";
            status = queryUpdatePerform(QD_ExternalKey, Query, ut);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The code is working but not as intended. I'd like it to perform the queries in succession, rather it appears to be performing the next query before the previous is complete.

Comment: Ahh correct! Maybe InvokePerform, can over come this issue but not sure.

Comment: My solution involves the use of Automation Studio so when I run the query through AS using InvokePerform() I can check the status and continue my loop until the Status is marked as no longer running. Reference: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131147/status-codes-of-program-object