# Status codes of Program object?

Tags: api, automationstudio

I am retrieving the status of an Automation and do not know what the status codes represent. I've seen documentation on this, but can no longer find it.

2 and 3 are being returned most frequently:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
// Create an API Retrieve RequestPerform request.
    var RetrieveRequest = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");

    // Set the request type
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(RetrieveRequest, "ObjectType", "Program");

    // Set the columns
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Program.Name");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Program.ObjectID");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveRequest, "Properties", "Program.Status");

    // Create a filter
    var RetrieveFilter = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
    // By ExternalKey/CustomerKey
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(RetrieveFilter, "Property", "CustomerKey");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(RetrieveFilter, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(RetrieveFilter, "Value", ExternalKey);


     // Add the filter to the retrieve
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(RetrieveRequest, "Filter", RetrieveFilter);

    // Do the retrieve
    var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
    var Program = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(RetrieveRequest, StatusAndRequestID); 
    var status = StatusAndRequestID[0];
    var requestid = StatusAndRequestID[1];

    //Find the ObjectID
    var objectid = "";
    var qd_status1 = "";
    for ( var c = 0; c < Program.length; c ++ ) {
        objectid = Program[c].ObjectID;
        qd_status1 = Program[c].Status;
    }   
</script>
```

**Output:**

qd_status1: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProgramStatusID Name    Description

-1  Error   Program errored out

0    BuildingError   Program errored out when it was being built

1    Building    Program is being built with activities, schedule etc.

2    Ready   Program is ready to be started

3    Running Program is running

4    Paused  Program is paused from its running state

5    Stopped Program has been stopped

6    Scheduled   Program has been scheduled

7    AwaitingTrigger Waiting for Trigger

8    InactiveTrigger Trigger is Inactive

9    Skipped Program step has been skipped

10   Initialized Program has been initialized