# Data Extract definition change filename pattern

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automation

Can I programmatically change Data Extract definition? I cannot find any example.

I am looking for something similar to QueryDefinition change example:

```
var qd = QueryDefinition.Init('my_definition'),
status = qd .Update({
                  QueryText: "SELECT A FROM B"
              });
qd.Perform();
```

Marcel

Comment: What you want to update is not a Data Extract definition, but a Query Activity. Did you check this thread? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130619/ssjs-update-and-perform-query-definition

Comment: data extract i want to change and thought that it should be similar as with querydefinition :)